# How to deploy zip file to Nexus repository via Maven

Tags: xml, maven, nexus

I have a zip file which I want to deploy to a Nexus repository. So I created a pom.xml file and a settings.xml file to do this. I was able to successfully upload to nexus but it seems it was deployed as a jar file

When I put in `<packaging>zip</packaging>` element, maven doesn't recognize it. How can I accomplish my goal of deploying my zip file to nexus? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Contents of directory:
1. content.zip
2. pom file
3. settings file

**pom.xml:**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.ct.ty16.archive</groupId>
    <artifactId>contentzip</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Deploy-zip-file</name>
    <description>Deploy zipped content file on Jenkins to Nexus</description>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </project>
```

Note: I am not using maven to build the content.zip file, just upload it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the mvn deploy file - https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Answer (score 5):

Define your server in the settings.xml

```
<servers>
  ...
  <server>
    <id>server-snapshots</id>
    <username>server-snapshots-username</username>
    <password>server-snapshots-password</password>
  </server>
  ...
</servers>
```

Define deploy-file configuration for `deploy` phase

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>deploy-file</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</file>
        <repositoryId>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.id}</repositoryId>
        <url>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}</url>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <packaging>zip</packaging>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Define the snapshotRepository

```
<distributionManagement>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>server-snapshots</id>
    <name>Snapshots repository (snapshots)</name>
    <url>http://repository.com/repo/server-snapshots</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Execute `mvn deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Two handy snippets for this situation:

Deploy to remote maven repository:

First, save credentials to repo in your `.m2/settings`:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>your-nexus</id>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Than you can use this command to directly deploy zip file, without a need for creating project for this action:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=<group-id> \
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
  -Dversion=<version> \
  -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy> \
  -DrepositoryId=your-nexus \
  -Dpackaging=zip
```

Installing to local maven repository (if you wish to try if it will solve build or so):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -DgroupId=<group-id> \
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
  -Dversion=<version> \
  -Dpackaging=zip
```

Links to doc:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html